# How to locate user with leaflet locate?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to locate a user and set the map to this position with leaflet:

```
    <script>
    var map;

    function initMap(){
        map = new L.Map('map',{zoomControl : false});
        var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/mapnik_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2012 OpenStreetMap contributors',
            osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttribution});
        map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.930156,7.189230), 7).addLayer(osm);
    }

    function locateUser(){
        map.locate({setView : true});
    }
</script>
```

On execute the browser ask for permission, but then nothing happens? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: We don't know what leaflet is, or anything about what you are doing. That one line of code sounds good, but you really need to give us a little more. Perhaps a link to your code, as well as info on what you've tried so far. Also, go and accept some answers - you have questions from 9 months ago where you haven't accepted the answer!

Comment: I've edit the whole source in my first post. Leaflet is a map lib. Details here: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

Comment: Could you please paste your whole code? Have you included all required leaflet files? How do you detect the user's position? Are your functions being executed?

Comment: Another point to note is Leaflet locate functionality only works on https websites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an issue with the scope of your map variable. I have posted an example that fixes your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwbsU/3/

You should receive the browser geolocation popup when you click 'Find me!'.

Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a quick hack. I recommend this plugin https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-locatecontrol

```
var loadMap = function (id) {
    var HELSINKI = [60.1708, 24.9375];
    var map = L.map(id);
    var tile_url = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var layer = L.tileLayer(tile_url, {
        attribution: 'OSM'
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.setView(HELSINKI, 19);

    map.locate({setView: true, watch: true}) /* This will return map so you can do chaining */
        .on('locationfound', function(e){
            var marker = L.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).bindPopup('Your are here :)');
            var circle = L.circle([e.latitude, e.longitude], e.accuracy/2, {
                weight: 1,
                color: 'blue',
                fillColor: '#cacaca',
                fillOpacity: 0.2
            });
            map.addLayer(marker);
            map.addLayer(circle);
        })
       .on('locationerror', function(e){
            console.log(e);
            alert("Location access denied.");
        });
};

loadMap('map');
```

Comment: do you know how i can add a few options here, particularly: locateOptions: {maxZoom: 15}

Comment: Here is the doc http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-locate-options  you would just add it like map.locate({maxZoom: 15, ... })

Comment: Does leaflet-locateplugin works with Ionic(Android/iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can put all your code under getLocation() function and call that function at the loading of the webpage  and you should be all set. I used this way and as soon as browser loads it popups a question to share data.